# Change website colors in Firefox

Tags: firefox

I'm using Firefox to read sites that contain a lot of black text on white background (much like this one). What is the simplest way to give Firefox the option to switch the font and background color of a site so that it ends up as white text on a black background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select **Tools > Options > Content**

Then the "Colours" button.

Select white for the "Text" colour and black for the "Background", not forgetting to clear the "Allow pages to choose their own colours, instead of my selections above" option.

[image]

You might need to make sure that the "Use system colours" option is cleared as well.

Answer (score 1):

[Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/addon/2108) is your friend. It is the best (and the only?) tool for this.

You can find a lot of styles for Stylish on the following site:
 http://userstyles.org/

Comment: Methinks this is a lot more easy and flexible than Tools > Options > Content.

Comment: Are you sure? ;) Try managing it / disabling it, etc.