# Is there a way to change white backgrounds to a diffrent color during browsing?

Tags: windows-7, browsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change website colors in Firefox](https://superuser.com/questions/127356/change-website-colors-in-firefox)

I have Firefox, Opera and Chrome installed. I've been browsing a lot lately and my eyes are getting real tired right away. I rest every 45 minutes and stretch. Is there a mod or plugin that turns white backgrounds to something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Firefox you can change the default background color using the Tools->Options and selecting the "Content" tab.

Under "Fonts and Colors" select the "Colors" button.  Here you can choose the default text color and background color for website which do not specify a color.  You can also choose to override the settings the website has declared, but be warned things may end up looking really bad if you do that.

Comment: True but don't expect too much if you don't override... I think 99% of the sites have defined colors so your setting will almost never be used.